# How to Extend Firebase Session Cookies Beyond 2 Weeks

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Auth to have users authenticate using their Google Account. I found the token returned by `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken` is only valid for 1 hour. To allow the session to last longer I tried creating a session cookie as outlined in [Manage Session Cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies):

```
const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, {expiresIn}).then((sessionCookie) => {
    const options = {maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true};
    res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
    res.end(JSON.stringify({status: 'success'});
}
```

This code successfully created a session cookie and subsequent requests could be verified using `admin.auth().verifySessionCookie`. All was well until I tried increasing the `expiresIn` duration. It turns out that Firebase session cookies have a maximum expiration time of 2 weeks. [From the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies):

> Ability to create session cookies with custom expiration times ranging from 5 minutes to 2 weeks.

For this project I would prefer to have a user log in once and stay logged in. I tried extending the session on every interaction with the server but I didn't find any official documentation on how to do that. It seemed to make sense to call `admin.auth().createSessionCookie` on the server using the token returned by `admin.auth().verifySessionCookie`, but that failed with this error:

```
Failed to extend session: { Error: An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: "{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Invalid value at 'valid_duration' (TYPE_INT64), 604.8","errors":[{"message":"Invalid value at 'valid_duration' (TYPE_INT64), 604.8","domain":"global","reason":"badRequest"}],"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}"`enter code here`
    at FirebaseAuthError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:143:16)
    at Function.FirebaseAuthError.fromServerError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:173:16)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:726:49
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'auth/internal-error',
     message: 'An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: "{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Invalid value at \'valid_duration\' (TYPE_INT64), 604.8","errors":[{"message":"Invalid value at \'valid_duration\' (TYPE_INT64), 604.8","domain":"global","reason":"badRequest"}],"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}"' },
  codePrefix: 'auth' }
```

Is it possible to extend Firebase sessions on the server side without requiring the client to do any work? Is it possible to use Firebase auth with tokens with a longer lifespan than 2 weeks? If not, in there a standard approach on how to achieve incredibly long lived sessions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending it too long can be risky, as if the cookie is leaked, the window of attack will be quite wide. I don't recommend extending the session longer but if this is a requirement, you could try to do the following:

1. after verifying the session cookie on your server for the user and noticing it is about to expire.
2. mint a custom token for that user ID with Admin SDK
3. `signInWithCustomToken` with that custom token.
4. `user.getIdToken()` to get new ID token.
5. Exchange that ID token for a new session cookie.

The downside is that the claims in the session cookie will correspond to a custom token user.

Notice for client side sessions, the ID token passed around has one hour duration, even though the session is indefinite. This is because a refresh token lives on the device and is used to exchange new ID tokens. At any time, only the ID token is transmitted limiting the window of attack to one hour if that token is leaked.

I think it would be useful for Firebase Auth to offer an active duration functionality. That would be better for extending sessions continuously in short increments. This would be better than minting an indefinite or very long cookie. An active user would constantly have their session extended. This is not offered by Firebase Auth but you can file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/) for it.

Comment: Hello, my current flow right now is the user signs in on the client, then firebase sends back the id token. The id token is then sent to the server which calls ```create_session_cookie``` and sets the session cookie on the browser with a specific expiration date. Suppose that the user is idle and the session cookie will expire in 10 mins. If I implement what you outlined, would I be able to essentially "refresh" the session cookie? You mentioned that the downside is that the claims in the session cookie will correspond to a custom token user, can you elaborate why this is a downside?